# Insert ignore/unique index

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble understanding how do this. `commentid` is an id of a row in the `comment` table. The `vote` table has three columns: `id`, `commentid` & `username`.

What i want is to insert into the `vote` table only if the last two columns(commentid and username) doesn't exist.  `$commentids` is an array of multiple `$id` from the `comment` table.  How do i add a unique index to accomplish this?

```
$commentids = explode(".",$id);

foreach($commentids as $value) {
  $insert = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO vote 
                           (id, commentid, username) 
                         VALUES 
                           ('','$value','$username')", $this->connect);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `(commentid,username)` pair to be unique then:

```
alter table vote add constraint unique (commentid, username);
```

If you want each of `commentid` and `username` to be globally unique within the table then:

```
alter table vote add constraint unique (commentid);
alter table vote add constraint unique (username);
```

Comment: is that a seperate query inside the foreach loop?  and do i still use insert ignore?

Comment: @user892134: No, those are constraints that you'd add to your table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Comment: ok.. so is the table altered permanently? and how do i prevent a duplicate error when inserting?

Comment: @user892134: Yes, the table would be permanently altered (unless you dropped the constraints later of course). Using `INSERT IGNORE` rather than just `INSERT` will turn the PK or UNIQUE constraint violations into warnings and so skip duplicates without causing errors.